# SLF4J - how does it know which log type to use

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

SLF4J is a wrapper/facade class so you can use many different log types, such as logback, log4j , etc.  Let's say i want to use both logback and log4j and even a third like java.util.logging.  when i write a log like this:

```
    public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
    logger.info("Hello World");
  }
}
```

How do i know which logging framework its using ? Let's say i want it to use logback for this call, how do i know its not using another framework ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you understood, SLF4J is only an interface and needs an implementation. Basically, SLF4J does a call to :

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResources("org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class");
```

**EDIT** : now, this information is a bit outdated. It seems that nowadays, SLF4J uses `java.util.ServiceLoader` to load a `org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider` but the logic stays the same.

It means that you classpath must contain such a class with this fully qualified name.

Every logging framework that is compatible with slf4j defines such a class.

- If you dig into the code of `logback`, you will find a class named `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` which redirects to logback's implementation
- If you dig into the code of log4j, there is not such class but there is a binding framework between `log4j` and `slf4j` which is called `slf4j-log4j` which also define a class named `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` but which redirects to log4j's implementation.

So if you want slf4j to use a particular framework, just place the accurate jar in the classpath so that the corresponding implementation of `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` is found.

Here is the big picture (Source : http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. based on your response i am still not clear, all i want to know is how can i switch log frameworks in my code ?

Comment: @j2emanue if you want to have 2 implementations at the same time and be able to switch, I don't think that it is possible. But if you want to completely use logback instead of log4j for example, just replace log4j.jar with logback.jar.

Comment: Side note: `slf-log4j` is for Log4j 1.x.  The Log4J 2.x version is [`log4j-sl4j-impl`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl)

Comment: Great - thanks for making this clear. Though this led me to think: instead of using the `ClassLoader` in the code snippet you cited, can't SLF4J just do: `import org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder;` `StaticLoggerBinder s = new StaticLoggerBinder();`?

Comment: @flow2k No, because the class `StaticLoggerBinder` does not actually exist in SLF4J. Hence SLF4J itself would not compile with a `new StaticLoggerBinder()`. The class `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` with this exact full qualified name is defined in each adaptation layer (slf4j-log4j for log4j, etc). When SLF4J calls `ClassLoader.getSystemResources("org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder");`, and if an adaptation layer of SLF4J is present in the classpath, the corresponding implementation of `org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder` will be found.

Comment: Yes, I see what you're saying: `getSystemResources` does not make the compiler check the existence of the resource at compile-time so there is no issue there. But for my idea, I think we can still make it work: we just need to declare some dependency which implements `StaticLoggerBinder` at compile-time (i.e., put the dependency on the classpath at compile time), in order to generate the SLF4J jar (not a fat jar, so it includes the SLF4J bytecode only). Then we can switch out the `StaticLoggerBinder` dependency at deployment-time as usual. Am I making sense? I think this could work.

Comment: Since we're on the topic of the design of SLF4J - isn't the wiring of a concrete implementation to an interface exactly what a DI framework like Spring sets out to solve? So I suppose SLF4J could have just used the Autowiring feature of Spring - though admittedly, I need to dig into how Spring Autowires to know the pros and cons of this approach.