# How SLF4J/ JPA / JAX-RS find their implementation?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I'm learning Java and I find that there are many functionalities that are standardized :

- logging (using SLF4J)
- Persistence (using JPA)
- REST (using JAX-RS)
- SOAP (using JAX-WS)
- etc.

Let's take the Sl4j example : to use it correctly with log4j, we have to import the sl4j api, the sl4j/log4j bridge and the log4j implementation.

**Question** : In my class, I only communicate with the Slf4j API.

How my application knows about the log4j implementation ? 
Can someone explains what's happening exactly under the hood ?

Regards

Comment: Are you talking about `log4j-over-slf4j` module?

Comment: In my case, to use `log4j` through `slf4j`, I have the following JARs : `slf4j-api`, `log4j-core` and `log4j-sl4j-impl`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does slf4j bind to implementation? Does it really do so during compile time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829995/how-does-slf4j-bind-to-implementation-does-it-really-do-so-during-compile-time)

Comment: I updated the question's title because my question is more generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP asks a general question about how implementation is injected in some different cases.

## Logging

As sated in many answers, the `SLF4J` gives the interface and `log4j-slf4j` gives the implementation.

When you use the following statement:

```
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    ...
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooBarClass.class);
    ...
    LOG.debug("Foobar");
```

This is what is Happening:

We try to get the `Logger` from the `getLogger` method declared in the [`LoggerFactory` class](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.java) :

```
public static ILoggerFactory getILoggerFactory() {
        if (INITIALIZATION_STATE == UNINITIALIZED) {
            synchronized (LoggerFactory.class) {
                if (INITIALIZATION_STATE == UNINITIALIZED) {
                    INITIALIZATION_STATE = ONGOING_INITIALIZATION;
                    performInitialization();
                }
            }
        }
        switch (INITIALIZATION_STATE) {
        case SUCCESSFUL_INITIALIZATION:
            return StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton().getLoggerFactory();
        }
        ...
    }
```

So the magic happens at that statement:

```
return StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton().getLoggerFactory();
```

Because the classpath knows you implemented why, the `StaticLoggerBinder` implementation [is provided by `log4j`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-slf4j-impl/src/main/java/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.java).
As we can notice, `log4j` provides a with its own implementation:

```
private final ILoggerFactory loggerFactory;
...
private StaticLoggerBinder() {
    loggerFactory = new Log4jLoggerFactory();
}
```

And that's it !

## Persistence

For JPA/Hibernate part, you have to include `hibernate-jpa-api` and `hibernate-*` (core, entitymanager, etc).

Let's say you want to create an `EntityManagerFactory`:

```
    import javax.persitence.EntityManagerFactory
    import javax.persitence.Persistence;
    ...
    private static EntityManagerFactory EMF = Peristence.createEntityManagerFactory("foobar", null);
```

As for `List` and `ArrayList`, your classpath is fed with the interface and the implementation thanks to the JARs you import.

The `EntityManagerFactory` comes from the `hibernate-jpa-api` where we have a [`Persistence` class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.persistence/persistence-api/1.0/javax/persistence/Persistence.java).
We can notice that the `createEntityManagerFactory` method first lists all the **providers** and for each one of them, an `createEntityManagerFactory` is fired.
This is where the `hibernate` comes. It provides an `HibernatePersistenceProvider` that [implements the **`PersistenceProvider`** class](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider.java).

This is how `Hibernate` is injected.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about dealing with `slf4j` loggers, like:

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooClass.class);
```

then it is pretty simple: `org.slf4j.Logger` is just an interface, which has several implementations. In case of usage library `slf4j-log4j12`, this interface is implemented by class `org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter` which internally contains

`final transient org.apache.log4j.Logger logger;`

So it is simple adapter which wraps your logging requests and invoke them on `log4j` logger object:

```
public void debug(String msg) {
    logger.log(FQCN, Level.DEBUG, msg, null);
}
```

More specifically, proper `Logger` implementation is produced by `LoggerFactory` which firstly creates `Log4jLoggerFactory` via

```
StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton().getLoggerFactory()
```

, latter creates needed `Log4jLoggerAdapter` instance.

---

Generally it works via adaptation level like pictured on img from [documentation](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Slf4j` can be used with `log4j` or any other underlying logging library.

In case of `log4j`, it uses `log4j-slf4j-impl.jar` which contains necessary classes for communicating with `log4j` library.

As per the [documentation](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/02/logging-with-slf4j.html) -

> SLF4J doesn't resolve the logging implementation at execution, but
>   directly at the compilation with a bridging API. So more than the JAR
>   of SLF4J you need the following JARs : the bridging JAR and the JAR of
>   the implementation. Here is what you get with Log4J :

[image: Slf4j-log4j Integration]

Answer (score 1):

The SLF4J manual refers to how under the hoop SLF4J finds the implementation to use : [Binding with a logging framework at deployment time](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping).

SLF4J refers the thing that allows to use an implementation (Logback, Log4J, etc...) as "SLF4J bindings" :

> As mentioned previously, SLF4J supports various logging frameworks.
>   The SLF4J distribution ships with several jar files referred to as
>   "SLF4J bindings", with each binding corresponding to a supported
>   framework.

You have as many SLF4J bindings as implementations of SLF4J.
And of course, an implementation API may have distinct "SLF4J bindings" according to its version :

> To switch logging frameworks, just replace slf4j bindings on your
>   class path. For example, to switch from java.util.logging to log4j,
>   just replace slf4j-jdk14-1.7.22.jar with slf4j-log4j12-1.7.22.jar.

The binding with the implementation is not performed at runtime but at compile-time : each SLF4J binding is hardwired at compile time to use one and only one specific logging framework. 
So, you have just to include the SLF4J binding in the classpath (for example slf4j-jdk14-1.7.22.jar) so that SLF4J uses it :

> SLF4J does not rely on any special class loader machinery. In fact,
>   each SLF4J binding is hardwired at compile time to use one and only
>   one specific logging framework. For example, the
>   slf4j-log4j12-1.7.22.jar binding is bound at compile time to use
>   log4j. In your code, in addition to slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar, you simply
>   drop one and only one binding of your choice onto the appropriate
>   class path location. Do not place more than one binding on your class
>   path. Here is a graphical illustration of the general idea.

That's why it is generally advised to never place more than one SLF4J binding on the classpath as SLF4J is not designed to choose the implementation at runtime.